# Нужен механизм проверки, на наличие в строчке файла куска текста и при наличии онного изымать другие куски текста из этой же строчки

Tags: python, файлы, tkinter, поиск

Есть файл ".txt". В нём на каждой строчке расположено по 3 тип данных: Имя пользователя, пароль и почта. Я при помощи tkinter сделал поле с кнопкой, которая должна считывать вводимый пользователем e-mail и искать его по файлу с данными и при нахождении совпадения, считывать с этой же строчки логин и пароль. Каким не хитрым способом это можно было бы реализовать?
Пример строчек из файла:

```
da;312321;kol@oda.ee:  
bhfg;3123;pok@da.ik:
```

Comment: читаете файл построчно, разделяете по точке с запятой, проверяете 3й элемент на совпадение Куда уж менее хитро

Comment: @splash58 Был бы очень признателен, если бы вы предоставили пример.

Comment: Что из этих трёх пунктов вызывает у вас затруднения ?

Comment: @splash58 Собственно все 3 пункта, ибо я новичёк не только в питоне, но и в целом в программировании и с подобным  раньше не сталкивался. Думаю мне было бы вполне достаточно отдельных примеров каждого из пунктов, а не всей программы в целом, так как тут тоже важно механизм этих процессов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно сделать так

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = f.read().splitlines() #(записываем в list каждую строчку)
    for el in nums: #циклом проходим по каждому элементу в list
        a=(el.split(";")[2]) #строку разбиваем в новый list , в качестве разделителя ;
        if "kol@oda.ee" in a.split(":")[0]: #вхождение подстроки в строку
            print(el.split(";")[0],el.split(";")[1]) # вывод имя пользователя и пароля если email найден
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогло!